# SQL Server - Lógica de query

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Observem o resultado abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o resultado da seguinte query:

```
select *,
isnull(h,isnull(f,isnull(d,isnull(b,isnull(a,0))))) as y1,
isnull(h,isnull(g,isnull(f,isnull(e,isnull(d,isnull(c,isnull(c,0))))))) as y2 from valor
```

---

Minha dificuldade é: sempre que `y2` apresentar um valor de uma coluna, `y1` deverá sempre apresentar a anterior, como está acontecendo na linha 2 da imagem acima.

Mas observando a linha 1 é um caso, a linha 3 outro caso e casos errados do que eu desejo fazer.

Será se alguém poderia me ajudar a montar esta query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, o [`COALESCE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) é seu amigo. Use-o. Com ele, sua query é simplificada para isso:

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(h, f, d, b, a, 0) AS y1, COALESCE(h, g, f, e, d, c, c, 0) AS y2
FROM valor
```

Observe que ainda há algo errado. No `y1`, não há os campos `g`, `e` ou `c`. No campo `y2`, não há o `b` e o `a`, e o `c` aparece duas vezes.

O `COALESCE` simplifica o seu problema e te fornece o `y2` prontamente, mas ainda não resolve para o `y1`. A [estrutura `CASE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) pode te ajudar identificando o primeiro campo não-nulo e então trazendo o campo anterior.

O resultado é isso:

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE
        WHEN h IS NOT NULL THEN g
        WHEN g IS NOT NULL THEN f
        WHEN f IS NOT NULL THEN e
        WHEN e IS NOT NULL THEN d
        WHEN d IS NOT NULL THEN c
        WHEN c IS NOT NULL THEN b
        WHEN b IS NOT NULL THEN a
        ELSE 0
    END AS y1,
    COALESCE(h, g, f, e, d, c, b, a, 0) AS y2
FROM valor
```

Answer (score 0):

Victor Stafusa, ficou show sua resposta! Não me lembrava mais da função `COALESCE`.

Porém ontem, logo após ter postado esta minha dúvida, havia conseguido solucionar o problema de uma forma diferente dessa sua, contudo com a mesma lógica e raciocínio utilizando a função `IIF` no lugar do `CASE`. Ficando a query assim:

```
select *,

iif(h is not null, g, iif(g is not null, f, iif(f is not null, e, iif(e is not null, d, iif(d is not null, c, iif(c is not null, b, iif(b is not null, a, '0'))))))) as y1,
isnull(h,isnull(g,isnull(f,isnull(e,isnull(d,isnull(c,isnull(b,0))))))) as y2
from valor
```

Agora posso juntar o melhor das duas queries.

Answer (score -3):

Pela minha resposta, você já pode desconfiar que você tem um problema de arquitetura de banco de dados...

```
WITH q (valor, ordem, id) AS
(
    SELECT a valor, 1 ordem, id
    FROM tabela
    WHERE a IS NOT NULL

    UNION

    SELECT b, 2, id
    FROM tabela
    WHERE b IS NOT NULL

    UNION

    ....

    UNION

    SELECT h, 8, id
    FROM tabela
    WHERE h IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT valor, id, ordem
FROM q
JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(valor) maximo FROM q GROUP by id) r
    ON (q.valor = r.maximo OR q.valor = (r.maximo - 1))
    AND q.id = r.id
ORDER BY id, ordem DESC
```

Comment: Editei a resposta. Confira agora.